# Are questions about the logistics/administration/practical matters in past research on-topic?

Tags: discussion

There is a recent question on Academia.SE about funding sources for mathematicians in the 19th century (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/171714/did-mathematicians-of-the-19th-century-apply-for-grant-money).

I think the question is fine on Academia.SE, there are other occasional [history of academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-history) questions there that are well-received, likely nothing needs to be done with this specific question to migrate it here or anything. However, I did suggest to OP that this site could be home to their question if it were not well-received, and given their interest I thought they'd find this site interesting if they weren't yet aware of it. After suggesting that I realized, well, **I** think it fits but also I don't really participate here so I may have gotten it wrong.

I didn't immediately find any meta discussion of this sort of thing, so I'd appreciate direction toward any discussion of the broader scope of what is on-topic here. Otherwise, I'd ask the more specific question in my title: are practical issues in the history of science and mathematics on-topic here, including how either individuals or groups are financed, academic structures, etc? Are there any guidelines on what makes a "good" vs "poor" question in this area?

Comment: I am quite sure such questions are on-topic here. Incidentally, there was a well-received question alone similar lines in HSE, https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52635/how-did-a-student-grant-work-in-18th-19th-century-western-europe.